# Neo4j pessimistic locking with JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, locking

I am currently writing Liquigraph, a migration tool for Neo4j.
I need to make sure only 1 client is executing migrations against the same instance at a time.

For this, I already started to write explicit locks as you can see in the following [class](https://github.com/fbiville/liquigraph/blob/02b276897b5d3c5595714c2054f03c284b0e7062/liquigraph-core/src/main/java/org/liquigraph/core/api/LockManager.java).

However, there is still a time window where client B can insert a lock node between client A check and write. In order to avoid this, I need to use pessimistic locking as described [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-pessimistic).

Currently, I do not see any way to use this with the JDBC driver: am I wrong? If I'm right, is there a way to somehow achieve pessimistic locking whether the database is embedded or remote?

Thanks in advance,
Rolf